# how to configure ubuntu 22.04 clients with synology dns server

Tags: 22.04, dns, dhcp

I've got the latest Synology and several Ubuntu 22.04 (fully updated) but empty.

- installed Synology's own DNS server: example.local
- installed Synology's own DHCP server.

The client do get an IP of the DHCP range I dedicated for them. Nice. But they do not get the domain options delivered so that I could resolve the FQDN with `hostname -f`. It simply shows the hostname that I've set in the client's hostname file. /etc/hostname

The resolv.conf shows merely:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search example.local
```

(That is an arbitrary nameserver as well. My name/dns server is 10.0.0.10)

A ping from one client to another would result in:

```
ping worker-s-05

ping: worker-s-05: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

... or ...

```
ping worker-s-05.example.local
ping: worker-s-05.example.local: Name or service not known
```

I've added vendor (Ubuntu22.04) [options](https://www.iana.org/assignments/bootp-dhcp-parameters/bootp-dhcp-parameters.xhtml) to the DHCP Server, hoping that the synolgy dhcp server would broadcast the DNS/DHCP options to the clients and the clients would accept them.

- 64: example.local
- 15: example.local
- 65: 10.0.0.10 <-- my synology/dns/dhcp server ip
- 6: 10.0.0.10
- 119: example.local

Is there anything else I could do for my Ubuntu 22.04 clients to accept the domain example.local and resolve to a FQDN?

Comment: isn't this really a question for [Synology community](https://community.synology.com/enu/forum/1) The ubuntu client is less significant in this context.

Comment: @24601 maybe, but I would like to understand what the ubuntu client requires to accept the DHCP/DNS options. Is there limitations? requirements on what to enable to accept certain options? However, I just don't want to neglect the client error space.

Comment: I think it would be the same for any Linux client so not Ubuntu specific. When I have asked questions in the Synology Community before, they have been most helpful in successfully recommending courses of action. Worth asking them tbh.